# Napping between meat and milk

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, sleep

Someone told me this past Shabbat that if you take a nap (20 minutes or longer) after eating meat, that you can eat milk when you wake up.

They didn't give a source, and some quick Googling didn't give a source either. Has anyone else ever heard of this? Sources? Thanks!

Comment: Great sources, thank you both. Though they seem to disprove what this person had told me. Well... I'm off to make a cup of coffee! ;-)